# How to add .live to this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, infinite-scroll

My site is a music site that with 24 single song players on each page. The problem is that the player isn't loading on the newly loaded pages.

I am using infinite scroll on my website and I cant get a callback to work on my infinite scroll code, so from what I have researched, .live is the next step to take.

Unfortunately, I dont know how to implement .live into my code. I am not sure if it's even applicable for this situation.

Does anyone have any relevant examples or even help with the situation.

The audio player code is as follows:

```
    //Audio jquery

    $(function(){

    $(".audio").mb_miniPlayer({
    width:210,
    height:34,
    inLine:false,
    onEnd:playNext
    });

    var $audios = $('.audio');

    function playNext(idx) {
    var actualPlayer=$audios.eq(idx),
    $filteredAtoms = $container.data('isotope').$filteredAtoms,
    isotopeItemParent = actualPlayer.parents('.isotope-item'),
    isoIndex = $filteredAtoms.index( isotopeItemParent[0] ),
    nextIndex = ( isoIndex + 1 ) % $filteredAtoms.length;

    $filteredAtoms.eq( nextIndex ).find('.audio').mb_miniPlayer_play();
    };  
    });
```

Not sure if this is needed, but here is the infinite scroll code:

```
  //Inifinite Scroll

  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.square'
  });

  $container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : '.square',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
      }
    },

  // call Isotope as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
      var $newElements = $(newElements);

  // add hover events for new items
      bindSquareEvents( $newElements );
      setTimeout(function() {
      $container.isotope('insert', $newElements );
      }, 1000);
      });
```

Div example:

```
<div class="square pop">
 <!-- DJ Picture -->
<img src="Pictures/adrianlux.jpg" class="img1" />
        <div class="boxtop">
        <span class="genre">Pop</span>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
        <a class="close" href="#close">&times;</a>
        <!-- DJ Name -->
        <h1>Adrian Lux</h1>

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <h2>Alive (Extended Mix)</h2>

         <!--Song Description(179 characters with spaces)-->
        <h4>Although this is not truly a pop song, I don't think it can be classified as anything else. The transition from spoken-word lyrics to rising vocals is wonderful as is the drop that follows.</h4> 

           <div class="buttons">
           <!--Song file info-->
            <div class="player">
            <a id="m75" class="audio {skin:'#010101',showVolumeLevel:false,showTime:false,showRew:false,ogg:'MP3/Adrian Lux feat. The Good Natured - Alive (Extended Mix).ogg'}" href="MP3/Adrian Lux feat. The Good Natured - Alive (Extended Mix).mp3"></a></div> 

                <!--Download Link-->
                <div class="download">
                <a href="MP3/Adrian Lux feat. The Good Natured - Alive (Extended Mix).mp3" title='Right Click and Save Link As'>
                <img src="img/dlicon.png"/></a>

                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use `.live()`, use `.on()`. And if `.on()` is not available (eg. when you are using jQuery < 1.7), then `.delegate()` is the way to go (it is more efficient and its syntax encourages more reasonable use cases). To sum up: 1) use `.on()`, 2) if there is no `.on()`, use `.delegate()`, 3) if there is no `.delegate()`, then use `.live()`.

Comment: Okay. I was also looking at .on, but could not find much information on how to implement it on situations like this. I haven't looked into .delegate though. I will do that now.

Comment: That comment is not helpful at all in this situation, no form of delegation can help him here.

Comment: @user1063192: They are very similar, except `.live()` has been deprecated (more or less) in favour of `.delegate()` and `.delegate()` has been deprecated in favour of `.on()`. If you have `.on()`, then use it, giving the `selector` argument (see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). But to get some help, you will probably need to explain how your site works in more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way any event delegation .on() .live() .delegate() would help is if you planned on abbandonning mb_miniPlayer completely and writing your own javascript. Then sure, you could take all of the functionality of the "song players" (eg:start,stop,pause) away from the particular elements and move them up to something persistent on the page.

What all event delegation does is move control. For example, an alternative to binding a plain old click handler could be as follows:

```
$('a.mylink').on('click',function(){
    alert('I see you!');
});
```

But the same functionality could be accomplished with:

```
$('body').on('click','a.Otherlink',function(){
    alert('I see you too!');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VTn7x/1/)

What we have done is move the event handler from the `<a>` itself, up to the `<body>`. The second argument of .on() is an optional selector to filter with. In this case, of all the clicks which happen on the `<body>` we are only interested in those that originated from `<a class="otherLink">`.

Unfortunately this is of little help for your problem. .live() is not the cure-all that some seem to think. It doesn't magically make the page "more live". What it does do is move the event handling from something that might be transient (like a link we could generate dynamically) to something more permanent (the body is a pretty safe target).

The problem here is you infinite scroller, if something doesn't exist on the page when you run your javascript (the part that is instantiating the players) then they can't very well be "activated". And no use of .live() .delegate() OR .on() can bring them back.

What you can do, is find a way to hook into the offending javascript and make it do what you need it to, which is to instantiate your newly loaded players. **What is the plugin you are using? I may be able to offer a way to hook into it.**

**EDIT:** This will be a little tricky without being able to test your page, but it looks like your infinite-scroll plugin provides a callback which fires every time it loads new content and you are using it already. That is perfect, and we add on there:

```
function( newElements ) {
    var $newElements = $(newElements);

    $newElements.find(".audio").mb_miniPlayer({
        width:210,
        height:34,
        inLine:false,
        onEnd:playNext
    });
```

The idea here is to search the new content for new audio players and activate them. Since playNext() was defined within the same function, using that as your 'onEnd' should work fine.

Comment: You would be my savior if you could help me with this.

Comment: sorry, I meant what is the "infinite scroll" plugin that you are using. It is the offender here. The audio player is doing exactly as it has been asked to do.

Comment: it is saying Error: playNext is not defined on my FF console

Comment: figured it out. I added the entire audio jquery to what you just answered. thank you so so much for this. I have been working on this for the past 2 weeks. I suck at javascript. I cant believe this. Thank You.

Comment: Hey Sintheta, I have a question for you... I am not sure if this is related to my audio code or with the callback, but would you be so kind to take a look... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977541/trouble-with-continuous-play-on-html5-audio-player-with-pages-loaded-from-infini/8978501#8978501